# Encryption/copyright my powershell PS1 file

Tags: powershell, user-interface, win32gui

I have completed my powershell tool and was wondering if there is a way I can stop people from making changes to it in the future.

I know I can compile it into an exe file but what I really want is to stop the amendment of the code so it will always have my name against it, quite proud of my tooll so would hate the idea of if I left the organisation and they still uses it someone comes and changes a few lines of code and it's claimed as their own.

Even if it was encrypted with a password inside the code maybe.

Any ideas on how this would work or if it is possible?

Cheera

Comment: You do realize that what you're asking would basically prevent people from fixing bugs in your code if it was possible (which it isn't)? Besides, even if you were the one writing the code, the legal owner is most likely your employer.

Comment: no one "owns" code.  As soon as it's written and used it becomes part of the collective.  write good code and polish your reputation.  Add it to github and breakers will dull theirs.  Shine on.

Comment: you may want to look into code signing: https://www.darkoperator.com/blog/2013/3/5/powershell-basics-execution-policy-part-1.html

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns Sorry to burst your bubble, but publishing code you've written at work to Github (or other places like it) without getting permission from your employer first may get you into serious legal trouble.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers and once that code is written you cannot "unsee" that code and will use it in future projects. Read carefully.  I'm not advocating putting corporate code on github.  Adam is concerned about `his` reputation.  My advice is sound for maintaining a personal reputation for code you believe you "own."  Which of course raises the question of why you are wanting people to look at if you want to control it.  But `that` is a different question.  I'll keep you in mind the next time I don't need legal advice.

Comment: You've got some good replies in the comments already as well as an answer but I would just like to add that adding a comment-section for a simple changelog within the script itself could be a quite nice thing. It's no version control but it's inviting collegues to participate and add to it rather than have them claim it as entirely there own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption/copyright my powershell PS1 file

You can add your copyright notice in the Synopsis.
You could even apply a encoded picture with whatever message you want.

You cannot encrypt your code, but you can encode/obfuscate it (but this is easily reversed by anyone willing to try - just as a DLL can be reverse engineered - it's what crackers / hackers and developers do when needed)

[PowerShell Obfuscator](http://www.powertheshell.com/powershell-obfuscator)

[Invoke-Obfuscation: A PowerShell Command & Script Obfuscator!](http://pentestit.com/invoke-obfuscation-powershell-command-script-obfuscator)

All this obfuscation and encryption stuff will set off you security guys / monitors, and should as it's what hackers are using to evade people and compromise systems.

You can sign your code with a code signing certificate

[Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Sign Windows PowerShell Scripts with an Enterprise Windows PKI? (Part 2 of 2)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/06/17/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-2-of-2)

You can then convert it to and .exe using [ps2exe](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5) , again this can be reversed.

Any PowerShell code run on a system has to be decoded by the host for it to run, meaning, anyone can get your code by looking at the Windows PowerShell log. This is one way white hats de-obfuscate code when faced with an attack using code obfuscation.

That is about as close as you can get, but what Ansgar Wiechers said and even if you never leave the employer, you still have to leave the source code in plain text to be able to pass on to who'd replace you if you got promoted, move to a new team or left the company or heaven forbid left your mortal coil and folks need to address your code.

Doing what you are saying, is the reason Y2K was a thing. Dev's of the original code were no where to be found to correct their junk code. It is why many companies are still on WinXP and older, because the dev compiled the code to that old stuff and thus cannot be changed.

Since MS has released all of PowerShell as Open source, then why would you want to do this? Since every bit of code on MS PowerShell Gallery is open source, same deal.

Lastly, I am pretty sure you code is not all original. Meaning are you saying, that you did not look at any other resource / sample / example to reach you final script product?
Did you credit the authors of those samples / examples in your code?

If you are just trying to prevent a normal user from messing with your code the PS2EXE should be you most prudent route. Yet, still leave it stored for those who will follow you in plain text in a source control system, say VSS, GitHub, etc...

Comment: I'm not a paid developer but i did spend a great deal of time building the tool from scratch, mostly self made in the sense i asked a few questions on this site so i haven't actually had to reference many sources. 
i think maybes you guys probably work in a very effective and efficient work place :D i was tasked with creating this tool after the last we had in place was so badly created and people were adding stuff removing stuff without asking. 
this is the only reason i wanted to lock it down as such, i don't want it to be a case of no body touch it i just want to minimise the risk

Comment: @Adam Maybe using a version control system would be the right approach to minimise this particular risk.